# locating the "send item" on outlook Office using Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

hi I am trying to click the New Group on the menu on office365
on chromedriver using selenium
but when I run the script I made it doesn't work
here is how and where the "New Group" button located http://prntscr.com/od9pec

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 #after login and browsing to the home page
 time.sleep(3)
 nwgroup=driver.find_element_by_link_text('New group')
 time.sleep(4)
 nwgroup.click()
```

please help

Comment: post the markup, could be a frame...

Comment: yes it looks like it is a frame,but I couldn't find the specific id or name for this frame

Comment: you can probably use index of zero... (I'm guessing it's zero, but hack it out until it works...)

Comment: how can I use this as a command for selenium

Comment: i guess driver.switch_to.frame(0)

Comment: it didnt work with index 0,1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a link text for this element. Use xpath for New Group, works 100% checked with me personal office(see screenshot)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@title='New group']')
```

[image]